# How to use ng-cookies in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, cookies

How to use ng-cookies in AngularJS?

please see this example :

```
angular.module('myAdminApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies']).controller('navCtrl', function ($cookies) {
              $cookies.put('logOff', 'success');
              window.location = getBaseUrl() + 'Cpanel/Login';
});
```

and in login page :

```
angular.module('myLoginApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies']).controller('loginCtrl', function ($cookies) {
    var r = $cookies.get('logOff');// always value is undefined
});
```

why `r` is `undefined` ?

Comment: why are you creating an whole new angular module just to navigate to login page ?

Comment: This is just one example. Because  I want to know the why `r` is `undefined`.